# Can't add weblogic 12.2.1.4 server to eclipse

Tags: oracle, eclipse, weblogic

When trying to add the runtime environment for weblogic 12.2.1.4 eclipse gives me an error that the path does not contain a valid weblogic server install or the installed version is not supported. I am sure that I installed this version of weblogic correctly because I was able to add and run a server using netbeans. I currently have weblogic version 12.1.3 12.2.1.2 and 12.2.1.3 all working on eclipse so I did not think it was an issue with my OEPE version on eclipse. Just to be sure I downloaded a new version of eclipse from oracles website over [here](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/oepe-v12219-downloads.html) but I still was not able to add a runtime environment for 12.2.1.4
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wls 12.2.x requires admin rights under windows now, it could be why OEPE does not find your WebLogic installation.
I confirm that OEPE 12.2.1.9 (Eclipse Photon) should be used with WLS 12.2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with my OEPE version on eclipse. Installing the lastest version of eclipse from oracle solved all issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happened by some missing tools or updates so I solved it by going to "help" in eclipse and then "install new software" then paste this link
https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.10/photon/repository/
inside 'work with' box then download all the oracle tools and oracle MAF then you restart eclipse and do it again and it should work.